# Problems installing/running Rstan

Tags: r, stan

I tried installing and running Rstan - but no luck. There were a lot of errors in installing. Something to do with 'fansi' package. If I somehow managed to overcome them - when I try to run `example(stan_model, package = "rstan", run.dontrun = TRUE)` or any other basic intro code I get errors. It keeps throwing compilation errors. I even uninstalled R+Rtools+RStudio completely, and then installed latest version (4.1, rtools40, RStudio 1.4.1). Still no luck.

> Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose)
> :    sh: line 1: C:/Rtools/usr/mingw_64/bin/g++: No such file or
> directorymake: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:245:
> file3638d1d4a72.o] Error 127 In addition: Warning message: In
> system(paste(CXX, ARGS), ignore.stdout = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) :
> 'c:/nrn/mingw/usr/mingw_/bin/g++' not found

There are 2 weird things - 1st, there is no more `C:\Rtools`, but rather `C:\rtools40`. 2nd it refers to `C:\nrn` which is another program not related to R.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can `rstan` be installed as a binary, e.g. from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/rstan_2.21.2.zip) ?

Comment: Do you have a `.Rprofile` or `.Renviron` file in your home directory? Those files aren't removed when you uninstall R and can effect the paths to build tools. And is there a reason you are trying to build from source rather than use the CRAN compiled binary?

Comment: @BenBolker I made a mistake - the rstan actually installs (though I had problems with that too), there are some errors regarding fansi package. But if I try running `example(stan_model, package = "rstan", run.dontrun = TRUE)` I get this error.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: @MrFlick I just followed the instructions of `https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started`

Comment: @MrFlick your hint was good - I should have been more careful in following the instructions (even though the installation process is a bit over complicated). I deleted the .Rprofile, and followed the instructions here (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) to also change the make file - and now it works